# Susskind & Hrabovsky: For any system $F_i=-\partial_{i}V$?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, conservative-field

In the following $\left\{x\right\}$ means a configuration point in $3N\text{-dimensional}$ configuration space.  Each $x_i$ represents one coordinate of one particle of the system of $N$ particles.

In *The Theoretical Minimum: What You Need to Know to Start Doing Physics
By Leonard Susskind, George Hrabovsky, Lecture 5, p. 100, Equation (5)*, the reader is told:

> It is a basic mathematical expression of one of the most important principles of physics:
>
> *For any system there exists a potential $V\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)$ such that*
>   $$F_{i}=\frac{\partial{V\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)}}{\partial{x_i}}.\tag{5}$$

I don't find that assertion objectionable, but it seems like the type of statement which, had I made it, I would be told that I don't know what I'm talking about.

Quite often we find discussions which separate forces expressible as the gradient of a potential from "non-conservative" forces.  But that may be more a matter of convenience than a valid segregation of forces in Nature.

**Is the above quoted statement a generally accepted principle of physics?**

---

I said that I don't find the quoted statement objectionable; but that is not entirely true. It implies that Nature is fundamentally divisible into particle and void.  An assumption that I do not make.  But this is the realm of metaphysics.

Comment: Without more context, this is just not a correct mathematical statement.

Comment: How so?  What part do you have a question about?  The mathematical expression is rather typical to me.

Comment: But like you say, not every vector field is conservative. It is correctly written, but it's false.

Comment: As Javier correctly points out, there exist non-conservative forces $F$ that don't have potentials $V$. Are you sure that you are quoting all relevant context?

Comment: To paraphrase a quote by Feynman, what Susskind says is true for the simple systems studied by physicists - but physicists leave the more complicated real-world stuff for engineers to worry about. (Try modelling "friction" starting from the strictly conservative forces between sub-atomic particles, to see what Feynman meant!)

Comment: @Qmechanic From a few paragraphs earlier: "It is quite possible to imagine force laws that do not come from differentiating a potential energy function, but nature does not make use of such nonconservative forces."

Comment: He probably means that every _fundamental_ force is conservative. Nonconservative forces only appear if there's stuff going on you're not accounting for, like energy dissipating into heat.

Comment: General tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451)

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that Susskind & Hrabovsky a few paragraphs before OP's quote write the following disclaimers:

> It is quite possible to imagine force laws that do not come from differentiating a potential energy function, but nature does not make use of such *non-conservative* forces.

and

> It is generally not true that if you have a set of functions $F_i(\{x\})$, that they can all be derived by differentiating a single function $V(\{x\})$. It would be a brand-new principle if we asserted that the components of force can be described as
>   (partial) derivatives of a single potential energy function.

It seems that Susskind & Hrabovsky merely try to convey that [conservative forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) & [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) are useful principles, especially for fundamental forces and systems where energy is conserved, not that one cannot construct counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

Since force is dimensionally the gradient of energy, the statement is correct *if* F denotes a force and V denotes an energy. Usually V denotes a potential, in which case F should mean some kind of field. Also, F should be a tensor of one rank less than V.

Inconclusion, this statement is vacuous.